# Difference between Space utilization and Load factor in hashtable

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

What is the difference between Load factor and Space utilization in a Hashtable? Please, someone explain!

Comment: This question was tagged as C++ until legends2k removed that tag. Was it meant to be a question about the terminology used in C++, or a general terminology question?

Answer (score 1):

**Load factor**

Definition:

> The **load factor** of a Hashtable is the ratio of elements to buckets. Smaller load factors cause faster average lookup times at the cost of
>   increased memory consumption. The default load factor of 1.0 generally
>   provides the best balance between speed and size.

In other words, too small `load factor` will lead to faster access to the elements (while finding a given element, or iterating, ...) of the HashTable but also requires more memory usage.

In the contrary, high load factor will be slower (in average), with less memory usage.

A *`bucket`* holds a certain number of items.

*Sometimes each location in the table is a bucket which will hold a fixed number of items, all of which hashed to this same location. This speeds up lookups because there is probably no need to go look at another location.*

- **Linear probing as well as double hashing :** *The load factor is defined as `n/prime`,  where `n` is the number of items in the table and `prime` is the size of the table. Thus a load factor of 1 means that the table is full.*

Here is an example of benchmark (here realized in the conditions of a large `prime` number):

```
load        --- successful lookup ---        --- unsuccessful lookup ---
factor         linear       double              linear         double
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.50           1.50         1.39                2.50           2.00
0.75           2.50         1.85                8.50           4.00
0.90           5.50         2.56               50.50          10.00 
0.95          10.50         3.15              200.50          20.00
```

Table [source](http://cis.stvincent.edu/carlsond/swdesign/hash/hash.html).

- **Some hash tables use other collision-resolution schemes :** *For example, in separate chaining, where items that hash to the same location are stored in a linked list, lookup time is measured by the number of list nodes that have to be examined. For a successful search, this number is `1+lf/2`, where `lf` is the load factor. Because each table location holds a linked list, which can contain a number of items, the load factor can be greater than 1, whereas 1 is the maximum possible in an ordinary hash table.*

**Space utilization**

The idea is that we store records of data in the hash table. Each record has a `key` field and an associated `data` field. The record is stored in a location that is based on its key. The function that produces this location for each given key is called a `hash function`.

Let's suppose that each key field contains an integer and the data field a string (array of characters type of string). One possible hash function is `hash(key) = key % prime`.

Definition:

> The **space utilization** would be the ratio of the number of full used buckets (relatively to the load factor) to the total number of buckets reserved in the hash table.

*For technical reasons, a prime number of buckets works better, which (modulus the number of filly used buckets) can consists in a **waste of memory**.*

---

**Conclusion :** Rather than having to proceed through a linear search, or a binary search, a hash table will usually complete a lookup after just one comparison! Sometimes, however, two comparisons (or even more) are needed. A hash table thus delivers (almost) the ideal lookup time. The trade-off is that to get this great lookup time memory space is wasted.

***As you can see, I am no expert, and I'm getting information while writing this, so any comment is welcome to make this more accurate or less... well... wrong...***

> ```
>          I switched it in Community Wiki mode (Feel free to improve)
> ```

Comment: Nope, that link has a different definition :-)

Comment: Quote from here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, what link are you talking about ?

Comment: "The load factor of a Hashtable determines the maximum ratio of elements to buckets". That is different to what you are saying (which might be correct for certain types of hash table).

Comment: Does it sound better to you ?

Comment: This definition of _load factor_ is that used by the MSDN documentation. I wouldn't say that's how the term is normally used. I'd rather say the load factor refers to the actual number of keys per bucket, not to the maximum one.

Comment: What about the other term, _space utilization_?

Comment: As you can see, I am no specialist, and I'm getting information while writing this, so any comment is welcome to make this more accurate or less wrong...

Comment: @jogojapan "The load factor of a Hashtable determines the ratio of elements to buckets." Actually, that would be the strictest, most precise definition of a load factor, according to the data structures professor I had.

Comment: @bbill Yes but I made an edit. The original definition, which was controverted by jogojapan, was "The load factor of a Hashtable determines the `maximum` ratio of elements to buckets"...

Comment: Didn't see that. Now that I read it more carefully, maybe the definition should read, "The load factor of a Hashtable `is` the ratio of elements to buckets"

Answer (score 0):

`Load factor` is a measure of how full the hash table is filled with respect to its total number of `buckets`. Lets say, you have 1000 buckets and you want to only store a maximum 70% of this number. If `load factor` ratio  exceeds (more than 700 elements are stored) this maximum ratio, hash table size can be increased to effectively hold more elements .

`Space utilization` is the ratio of the number of filled buckets to the total number of the buckets in a hash table.

Usually, when load factor increases, space utilization increases and in an `ideal` hash table, load factor and space utilization should be linearly related to each other. However, in most cases, space utilization is a `sublinear` function of load factor because some buckets are assigned to hold more than 1 elements in case of high load factor ratios.

In order to obtain a hashing performance close to the ideal case you may need a `perfect hashing function`.

> A perfect hashing function maps a key into a unique address. If the
>   range of potential addresses is the same as the number of keys, the
>   function is a minimal (in space) perfect hashing function

Comment: The way you explain it makes it appear as if the load factor was the upper bound for space utilization. Did you confuse `load_factor` with `max_load_factor`?

Comment: The load factor is the number of entries *per bucket*.

Comment: @juanchopanza, sorry for ambiguity, with total capacity, I meant total number of buckets

Comment: It is still confusing after your edit: total capacity != number of buckets.